# Multiple chars in C++

Tags: c++

How do I concatenate the `DataBuffer` correctly? coming from PHP to C++ isn't easy haha, what exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
while(true) {
    DWORD TitleID = XamGetCurrentTitleId();
    char DataBuffer[] = "Here's the current title we're on : ";
    char DataBuffer[] = (DWORD)TitleID;
    char DataBuffer[] = "\n\n";
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(DataBuffer);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to initialize `char DataBuffer[]` 3 times, that is an error.

Comment: That depends what you are trying to achieve? It's waaay off for calculating pi, for instance. Are you trying to concatenate 3 strings into 1?

Comment: @ArunA.S I see that error in the console, how should it be done? as I need to append chars which is why I tried splitting it into 3

Comment: @BoBTFish yeah sir, that's correct

Comment: Then Edit your question and add that part to it.

Comment: use `strcat()` to concatenate.

Comment: Use `std::string` and `std::to_string`.

Comment: @Curtis Usually you would use [`strcat()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) to concatenate, but your buffer needs to be big enough for this (in your case it isn't). As you're asking for c++, I'd recommend using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ it is usual to work with the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) type. To create a string from multiple inputs, particularly if they aren't all strings in the first place, we use an [`ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

So you might build up your message something like this:

```
while(true) {
    DWORD TitleID = XamGetCurrentTitleId();
    std::ostringstream titleMessageSS;
    titleMessageSS << "Here's the current title we're on : "
                   << TitleID // already a DWORD, no need for the cast
                   << "\n\n";
    std::string titleMessage = titleMessageSS.str(); // get the string from the stream
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)titleMessage.size();
    // You don't do anything with this, so can't help you with how to write the string...
}
```

Now if you are using [`WriteToFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you need to get a `char` pointer out of the string. Do this using `titleMessage.c_str()`.

Alternatively, you can use `+` to build up a `std::string`, coupled with [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert the `TitleID` (so you can `+` it with a `string`).

Comment: This seems to work although I now get this error `error C2664: 'WriteFile' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::string' to 'LPCVOID'` when running this function `WriteFile(logFile, titleMessage, dwBytesToWrite, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);`

Comment: @Curtis Added a mention about using `c_str()` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas PHP has an automatic conversion to string, C++ hasn't (except for some cases).  You (usually) have to be explicit with your types. Fortunately, C++11 provides [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), which makes this a lot easier:

```
while(true) {
    DWORD TitleID = XamGetCurrentTitleId();
    std::string DataBuffer = "Here's the current title we're on : " 
                           + std::to_string(TitleID)
                           + "\n\n";
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = static_cast<DWORD>(DataBuffer.size());
    /* ... */
}
```